# Showing that the galois group for x^n+ax+b is doubly transitive

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I read [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178242731) that if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^n+ax+b $ and $\frac{x^n-\alpha^n}{x-\alpha}=a$ is irreducible, then the Galois group $G$ is doubly transitive.

I don't think I understand the reasoning here. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Using the notation of the paper. Remark that

$$\frac{X^n-\alpha^n}{X-\alpha}-a=\frac{X^n-ax+b}{X-\alpha} $$

When it's written that the equation $\frac{X^n-\alpha^n}{X-\alpha}=a$ is irreducible, it certainly means that $\frac{X^n-\alpha^n}{X-\alpha}-a$ is irreducible.

Let $F:=k(a,b)$ the base field, $K:=k(a,b,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ and $L:=k(a,b,\alpha)$. The Galois group  of $K/F$ is $G$.

Take $(r_1,r_2)$ and $(s_1,s_2)$ with $r_1\neq r_2$ and $s_1\neq s_2$ be two roots of $X^n-aX+b$. We are looking for $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot r_1=s_1$ and $g\cdot r_2=s_2$.

1. Justify and use the fact that the action of $G$ on $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is transitive to reduce to the case where $r_1=s_1=\alpha$.
2. With the reduction above, we are looking for $g\in G$ fixing $\alpha$ and sending $r_2$ to $s_2$. Justify that the Galois group of $K/L$ acts transitively on $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}-\{\alpha\}$ and conclude.

Note : I am not seeing exactly why the polynomials are irreducible...

In general, If a polynomial $P(X)$ is irreducible over $k$. Then its Galois group over $k$ acts transitively on the set $R$ of roots of $P$. If, furthermore for some root $r\in R$ $P(X)/(X-r)$ is also irreducible over $k(r)$ then its Galois group acts doubly transively on the set $R$ (using the same method as above).

Comment: The polynomial is $(x-\alpha_1)\dots(x-\alpha_{n-1})$ where $\alpha$s are roots of it, which should be reducible if $\alpha$ is a complex root...

Comment: @user319205 Well, I agree with you if $a,b$ are real but here $k$ is any field and $a,b$ are indeterminates over $k$.

Comment: well that explains things. I'm trying to show the case when $a, b$ are integers. Does that approach still apply?

Comment: @user319205, it depends on $a$ and $b$. But, it might apply. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: What if the roots are all complex (meaning P(X)/(X-r)) is factorizable in $k(r)$? In that case do we not have this?

Comment: @user319205 Indeed, it does not always happen, remark that $n=3$, $b=-2$ and $a=0$ gives an irreducible polynomial which verifies the doubly-transitive action (its Galois group is $S_3$) whereas $n=3$, $a=3$ and $b=-1$ gives an irreducible polynomial whose Galois group is $A_3$ which cannot acts doubly transitively on the set of roots.

Comment: But if $n=2, a=1, b=1$ the roots are all complex but we do have a doubly transitive action--does this not work for when $n>2$?

Comment: @user319205 If $n=2$ the action is doubly transitive and $P(X)/(X-r)$ is irreducible since it is of degree $1$ in this case.

Comment: Clement, how did you say, galois group of K/F is G

Comment: @user86925, this is the definition of $G$ in the given article.